# How to implement an atomic conditional operator function like a>b?c:d?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new to CUDA program, I need to implement an atomic function which is like that, `atomicMyFunc(int *address, int compare, int val1, int val2)`, "old" is the value located at the address.

I have been trying for it for several days but failed. 
It should be like that:

```
__device__ int atomicMyFunc(int * address, int compare, int val1, int val2)
{
    if(old>compare?val1:val2) // compare and then store val1 or val2 in the address
    {
        // do something
    }
    return old;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your atomic function using the atomic functions available in CUDA. I suggest to check the [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) for examples on how to build your atomic functions. Taking the example provided there as a starting point, I think the following function does what you want to do

```
__device__ int atomicMyFunc(int* address, int compare, int val1, int val2) {
    int old = *address;
    int assumed;

    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address, assumed, assumed > compare ? val1: val2);
    }
    while (assumed != old);

    return old;
}
```

It basically uses `atomicCAS()` in a loop in order to store the operation result only when it has been computed using the same value that is currently stored at the provided address.